# xml file not parsing in xamarin #

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to parse xml file in Xamarin C# for android app, but `XDocument` and some other errors are occuring and I am new to Xamarin. How can I parse xml file using C# in Xamarin ?

```
void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var mobilePath= Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
            var xmlFilePath = Path.Combine(mobilePath,"/DCIM/epub/OEBPS/content.opf");
            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            if (File.Exists(xmlFilePath))
            {
                builder.AppendLine("Ids of files");

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
                foreach (XmlElement element in doc.Root.Elements("manifest"))

                {
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: please provide file you are trying to parse. What errors you are getting?

Comment: Could you please debug it and check if the path is correct?